# a question in c programming about Getting the most the significant bit (MSB)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to know if these expressions are the same :

```
integer = (number >> INT_BITS) & 1;
```

and

```
integer = (1 << INT_BITS) & number;
```

Comment: No they're not the same, unless `INT_BITS == 0`

Comment: This might be the same `!!((1 << INT_BITS) & number)` depending  on what values they have?

Comment: @ChrisDodd I don't understand can you explain more about it

Comment: @Neil is that a logical not you used ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but `(n >> INT) & 1` is zero or one assuming `INT_BITS` is one less than the bits of unsigned `integer`, `b`, _eg_ 31. `(1 << INT) & n` is the same, but zero or `2^b`; the range of `!` is `{0,1}`, so I think that's the same under these conditions. But why?

Comment: @Neil thank you I was trying to get the NTH set of bit for an exercise and after I saw the answer I thought that I have answered it correctly in a different way

Comment: In general, there are possibly many different ways to manipulate the bits to get what you want, but, assuming the type is `uint32_t`, `n >> 31` is probably the the cheapest, (I don't think you need `&` if it's the highest bit.)

Comment: sorry it beats me I can't understand but thank you for your help